# How to save users changes in FastReport

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009, fastreport

In Delphi 2009 I install Fast Report 4.8, and create some reports. In my application I use these reports like this:

```
myfrxReport.ShowReport();
```

Now some users want to edit the report page, so I use frxDesigner.
But my problem is: "How can I save users changes ?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

u can this code :

```
    if not FrxReport.LoadFromFile(AFileName) then
      FrxReport.DesignReport
    else if TAppUtils.Confirm('You Have Authority To Design Report. Do You Want To Design Report ?') then
      FrxReport.DesignReport
    else
      FrxReport.ShowReport(True);
```

TAppUtils.Confirm : It is method to confirm user to do something or not

Answer (score 4):

Use the report as file, then the user can override that report file in the designer. Next time the report is loaded, the user loads the modified report.

```
frxReport.LoadFromFile(aFileName); //The report filename with the user changes
frxReport.PrepareReport(true);
frxReport.ShowReport;
```

Check also the `frxDesigner.Restrictions` options!